How to make double sidebar on flutter desktop?
I'm trying to create a double sidebar for Flutter Desktop using GetX, when the first sidebar menu is clicked it will update the menu on the 2nd sidebar,
I have tried using the pageview on the 2nd sidebar to update the menu but it doesn't work
Double Sidebar Flutter

Please take the tour and  also visit how to create minimal reproducible example. Do show what you've tried.

Your dashboard menu page can be hide under the drawer? like a real drawer or it should just fit at the right side of screen.?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@Aks yes under the drawer Side Menu 2, but on the right side of Side Menu 1

Try this: https://pub.dev/packages/multilevel_drawer
